# Edit javascript attribute in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in java script and now I am stuck with a little problem. I searched over the internet but I did not get the answer so I have to post the question.

Problem: I wrote `var x=1;` in jack.js and I linked it with my HTML file. Now I want to call that `var x=1;` in HTML page then I want to change it to `var x=2;`. So that the result will be shown 2 not 1 in HTML page.

Can anybody suggest me what should I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable will be available within the document, so just include a `<script>` tag within the HTML.

```
<script>
x = 2;
document.write(x);

// or:
$('#targetDiv').text(x);
</script>
```

Note this has to be after you include jack.js.

Comment: thanks for reply. I want to ask you that If I want to save that `x=2` in that jack.js file from html? then what i need to do?

Comment: The code in the js file will receive whatever the value of `x` is during execution. So for code that runs on page load, `x` will be 1 because HTML below has not yet changed it. Code that runs later, like a button click event handler, will see the new value of `x`.

Comment: thanks for reply.I got it now but I want to know that can we change any attribute value in a jack.js file forever from html page?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means. You can change any global variable like you did for x. But if the js file has some variables within limited scope (like in a function or encapsulation) these aren't accessible outside of the scope and you will not be able to change them from within the HTML file.

Comment: no problem, thanks for help. I tried it and its working. thanks again